# T-SQL CHECKSUM(*) function fails for tables with geography datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Does anybody know how I can get the checksum of the geography spatial datatype in a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure? I use checksum on other types with no problem but it throws an exception on geography saying:

> Argument data type sys.geography is invalid for argument 9 of checksum function.

I've run through the debugger in SQL Server Management Studio but I'm just not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it seems your position is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
I INT,
G geography
);

INSERT INTO T 
VALUES (1,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, 
                                             -122.343 47.656 )', 4326));
```

Then you are running a script that performs the following

```
SELECT Avg(Cast(CHECKSUM(*) As Float))
FROM  T;
```

You'll need to alter it so that it performs the following instead to avoid this error.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT I,
       CAST(G AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS G
FROM T       
)
SELECT Avg(Cast(CHECKSUM(*) As Float))
FROM  CTE;
```

Or maybe

```
SELECT Avg(Cast(CHECKSUM(I,CAST(G AS VARBINARY(MAX))) As Float))
FROM  T;
```

But you can't use `*` with these tables anyway.

Comment: In addition it tells me: Operand data type varbinary(max) is invalid for avg operator since avg is being used elsewhere

Comment: Is there some way to case the geography type to something else when encountered? I just don't know how to do this in stored procedure syntax.

Comment: @Pugz - The code in my answer does not give the same error. Please show how you are trying to use it.

Comment: I'm pretty much doing this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/499901/Checksum-for-Database

It works great for any types that are NOT geography

Comment: Just to be clear... by types I mean types of the fields within the tables to be checked.